# Can someone explain the Flickr API and how security is established? Why not use AES instead of md5?

Tags: encryption, flickr

Just trying to understand Flickr's API setup, and how secure it really is.

[Flickr API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.howto.web.html)

Why do a MD5 hash and not something like AES?

Answer (score 1):

The hash is strictly a signature, so a one-way hash like MD5 is good enough for their usage.  If there's a collision (unlikely but possible) they'll just re-hash.

No need to make it more complicated than it has to be.